# How do I get access to the event object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a JavaScript object that is similar to this:

```
var MyClass;
MyClass = (function() {

    // private
    var $elems;

    // constructor
    function MyClass(selector) {
        $elems = $(selector);
        $elems.change(myEventHandler(e));
    }

    // event handler
    function myEventHandler(e) {
        var isSelected = ($(e.target).attr('checked') == 'checked');
        if (isSelected) {
            alert('You selected me');
        }
    }

    return MyClass;

})();
```

I call this class in my html doc like this:

```
$(function(){ 

    var myClass; 
    myClass = new MyClass(".MySelector");

});
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined MyClassJsFile.js:17
    MyClass MyClassJsFile.js:17
    (anonymous function) Step3:36
    f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWith jquery.min.js:16
    e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:16
    c.addEventListener.B
```

I thought that I was passing the event object to the event handler in this line of the constructor:

```
$elems.change(myEventHandler(e));
```

How do I pass the event correctly in this case?

Comment: What library are you using? Why dou you have a `$` in the name of you variable `$elems`?

Comment: @some he's using jQuery, and the leading `$` is a common hint to a jQuery developer that the variable in question contains a jQuery object and not a DOM element.

Comment: Yes, I am using jQuery. I like the naming convention where the name of a variable holding a jQuery object begins with a '$'.

Comment: Please tag the question as jQuery then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$elems.change(myEventHandler);  // or $elems.on('change', myEventHandler) in 1.7+
```

to just pass the reference to the right handler.  As it is you're *invoking* the handler immediately, and then attempting to bind the (non-existent) return value to the `change` handler.

Your check for a selected box is over-complicated, BTW.  You should be able to just write:

```
var isSelected = this.checked;
```

on the basis that jQuery will set `this` to be the actual DOM element that changed, and you can immediately check its boolean `checked` property.

Comment: @quakkels scratch that, I forgot that in a jQuery handler `this` is supposed to point to the clicked element, and not the current object.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the event handler with an undefined variable. Event handlers are functions, so just pass the function reference without calling it:

```
$elems.change(myEventHandler);
```